How to skip first column and first row in returned dataset for Google Sheets?
The current formula returns 2 columns and multiple rows. I want to remove the first column and the first row.
How can I do this inline within the same formula? (i.e. without leaving the results as they are and post-processing in another column) I've tried working with INDEX(...) and CHOOSEROWS(...), but unfortunately could not get the results I wanted.
=GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT", "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31))



Maybe nest your formula in QUERY():
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT","price",DATE(2024,1,1),DATE(2024,1,31)),"Select Col1 label Col1 ''")


Oh, yes, this is perfect. Just a quick addendum: Do you know whether or not it's possible to make sure that the original formula doesn't expand into multiple cells? Is it possible to force it to remain in just one cell as a "data cell" for future reference by queries without refetching over the network?

@AlanSTACK please ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead.

offset:
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT", "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31)), "offset 1", )


then index it:
=INDEX(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT", "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31)), 
 "offset 1", ),,2)


and restriction can be done with:
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(INDEX(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT", "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31)), 
 "offset 1", ),,2), 20, 1)


